# Problem with Task.WhenAll How can I find out if each task was completed?

Tags: c#

I only want to set AllMethodsCompleted = true if all the tasks in TasksList were completed successfully. But I get an error message when I want to find out if everything was completed successfully. What am I doing wrong?

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

```
public async Task PlayerAccountDetails()
{
    var playerCountryData = GetPlayerCountryData();
    var playerTagsData = GetPlayerTagsData();
    var TasksList = new List<Task> { playerCountryData, playerTagsData };

    Task t = await Task.WhenAll(TasksList);
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        AllMethodsCompleted = true;
    else
        AllMethodsCompleted = false;
}
```

Comment: What are the return types of `GetPlayerCountryData()` and `GetPlayerTagsData()`?

Comment: Well are you trying to see whether the tasks has completed successfully without any error or exception? (OR) you just want to wait for the tasks completion?

Comment: I want to wait until the tasks have completed and I need to know if all the tasks were successful without any error or exception. @NateBarbettini They are private async Task GetPlayerCountryData and private async Task GetPlayerTagsData().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` will return a task that you can wait on for all the tasks to completion, so you just need to say:

```
public async Task PlayerAccountDetails()
{
    var playerCountryData = GetPlayerCountryData();
    var playerTagsData = GetPlayerTagsData();
    var TasksList = new List<Task> { playerCountryData, playerTagsData };

    await Task.WhenAll(TasksList);
    AllMethodsCompleted = true;
}
```

If any of the tasks were cancelled or threw an exception then the line `await Task.WhenAll(TasksList)` will throw an exception.

If you want to handle the failure of one of the tasks then you can do this:

```
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(TasksList);
    AllMethodsCompleted = true;
}
catch
{
    AllMethodsCompleted = false;
}
```

Comment: Should I create a try catch block for await Task.WhenAll(TasksList)? Like this: try{ await Task.WhenAll(TasksList);} catch{ AllMethodsCompleted = false;}

Comment: @Tobey60 You could, but the `Task` returned by `PlayerAccountDetails` will complete once `Task.WhenAll` has completed, so it might be better to defer this to the caller of `PlayerAccountDetails`.

Comment: @Tobey60 - I've updated the answer to show how you might handle an error in one of the tasks you are waiting on.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>)` returns `Task`.

By awaiting a (non-generic) `Task` you get no return value, hence why `Task t = await Task.WhenAll(TasksList);` won't compile. You simply need:

```
await Task.WhenAll(TasksList);
```

You could also write this as:

```
Task t = Task.WhenAll(TasksList);
await t;
```

Comment: How is your answer any different than the already posted one?

Comment: @Rahul Because the posted one doesn't explain the compilation error, which seems to be the key point of misunderstanding.